# SilverStripe - Undefined Index on DataObject onBeforeWrite

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Following the [official SS guide](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/extending_dataobjects/#onbeforewrite) on `DataObject` extension, I'm occurring on this exception:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PrezzoIva

Project panorama: a value must be computed and saved in pair with the other `DataObject` properties, before the main `write()` execution. 
Here's the situation (on SS 4.0.3):

```
[...] 
/**
 * Classe Prodotto
 */
class Prodotto extends DataObject
{
    // Dichiarazione Proprietà
    private static $db = [
        [...] 
        'PrezzoIva' => 'Currency',
        [...]
```

`onBeforeWrite` method:

```
    /**
     * Metodo gestione azioni salvataggio
     * Calcolo automatico prezzo lordo e scontato
     * Setter
     * @return void
     */
    public function onBeforeWrite()
    {
        // Controllo Record
        if (!$this->isInDb()) {
            $this->setPrezzoIva();
            [...]
        }
        if (!$this->record['PrezzoIva']) { // <--- This is the line involved
            $this->setPrezzoIva();
        }
        [...]

        parent::onBeforeWrite();
    }
```

The method called by the one above:

```
    /**
     * Metodo calcolo prezzo lordo IVA
     * Setter
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPrezzoIva()
    {
        // Controllo IVA
        if (empty($this->PrezzoIva)) {
            $prezzoIva = ($this->PrezzoUnitario * $this->Iva) + $this->PrezzoUnitario;

            // Salvataggio IVA
            $this->PrezzoIva = $prezzoIva;
        }
    }
```

Either changing `if (!$this->record['PrezzoIva'])` to `if (!isset($this->record['PrezzoIva']))` the exception is still thrown.

Thanks in advance for the support.

**UPDATE**

Seems that by nesting the controls inside `onBeforeWrite` apparently solves the issue, but it's not in accord with the business logic. On the first attempt of `onBeforeWrite`, the system doesn't see any `$this->record['PrezzoIva']` then fails. On the other side, if the controls being nested with `elseif`, in case other records missing, these are ignored. For now I'm still working on it. 
Meanwhile, I noticed that the involved field doesn't been initialized neither on `write()` calling. And this happens only with `$this->PrezzoIva`. The other fields being correcly saved. Here an example:

[image: DB screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on the right condition for this specific case solved the issue.
After the first `write()`, if there's no `this->record['PrezzoIva']` set or this one is equal to zero (according to `Currency` data type default value), the method is invoked:

```
        // Controllo Record
        if (!$this->isInDb()) {
            $this->setPrezzoIva();
        }
        if ((!isset($this->record['PrezzoIva'])) || ($this->record['PrezzoIva'] == 0)) {
            $this->setPrezzoIva();
        }
```

About the no-data written issue, I opened a new one here: [SilverStripe - No data written onBeforeWrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903348/silverstripe-no-data-written-onbeforewrite)