# SIlverStripe - No data written onBeforeWrite

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898205/silverstripe-undefined-index-on-dataobject-onbeforewrite), a `DataObject` extended with `onBeforeWrite` method doesn't write a specific property value on DB. In detail:

DataObject:

```
[...] 
/**
 * Classe Prodotto
 */
class Prodotto extends DataObject
{
// Dichiarazione Proprietà
private static $db = [
    [...] 
    'PrezzoIva' => 'Currency',
    [...]
```

`onBeforeWrite` method:

```
/**
     * Metodo gestione azioni salvataggio
     * Calcolo automatico prezzo lordo e scontato
     * Setter
     * @return void
     */
    public function onBeforeWrite()
    {
        // Controllo Record
        if (!$this->isInDb()) {
            $this->setPrezzoIva();
        }
        if ((!isset($this->record['PrezzoIva'])) || ($this->record['PrezzoIva'] == 0)) {
            $this->setPrezzoIva();
        }

        parent::onBeforeWrite();
    }
```

The method called by the one above:

```
/**
     * Metodo calcolo prezzo lordo IVA
     * Setter
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPrezzoIva()
    {
        // Controllo IVA
        if ((isset($this->PrezzoIva)) && ($this->PrezzoIva == 0)) {
            $prezzoIva = ($this->PrezzoUnitario * $this->Iva) + $this->PrezzoUnitario;

            // Salvataggio IVA
            $this->PrezzoIva = $prezzoIva;
        }
    }
```

There's no exception thrown. Basically, both on the first `write()` as well as in other saves, `PrezzoIva` is not being updated (it keeps the default one).
Here an extract to my DB after few `DataObject` edits:

[image: DB screen]

For now, I not figured out what causing this. A help of any kind will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Couldn't you simplify this to `if (!$this->PrezzoIva) { $this->PrezzoIva = {your value}; } return parent::onBeforeWrite();`? it's possible that your conditions are a little over the top

Comment: Hi @robert, I tried with your sugestion with the same result. Seems that there's something wrong with that particular property. For example, I tried with other ones in the same ```DataObject``` and they were initialized correctly. As well as remove the ```setDisabled(true)``` from the associated field, or changing the data type, but nothing. Even the straight assignment doesn't work (ex. ```$this->PrezzoIva = 10;```)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to watch the setters in SilverStripe. SilverStripe uses the `__set` function.

When you call `$this->PrezzoIva` it will search for a method called `setPrezzoIva`. If it cannot find a method with that name, it will call the method `setField`. Which will actually set the field like you want.

So the problem you're experiencing is because your method is called `setPrezzoIva`. Instead of setting the value, it is excecuting your method.

To fix this, change

```
$this->PrezzoIva = $prezzoIva;
```

to

```
$this->setField('PrezzoIva', $prezzoIva);
```

On a sidenote, I think Robbie is right, your conditions are too strict.

Comment: Thanks to Robert and @fatal. I refactored the logic of my methods. These are useful tips, sure I'll keep them in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, renaming the property involved with a different name, solved the issue.
The only cause that I could assume for good, Is that it could been caused by the fact that the `DataObject` has many properties with the same prefix-name (PrezzoIva, PrezzoScontato, PrezzoUnitario, etc.) and, in some mysterious way, was confunding the value/proper field association.